# Unable to visualize nodes, relationships in neo4j in browser

Tags: neo4j

I am unable to visualize the created nodes and relationships on the neo4j browser. Querying in the shell works, but in the browser it says (no changes, no records).

[image]

Comment: hi @riya you need to provide more information what you have tried so far

Comment: What kind of information? Sorry for sounding like a noob, really new to stackoverflow and neo4j.

Comment: You need to be as clear in describing the challenge being faced along with the code/config/environment description. Imagine asking the issue to someone very short of time so if its easy to understand, they will be able to attempt to answer

Comment: please Look this link for How to ask question on stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are getting the result of "no changes, no records" because you don't have any nodes in your database with the labels of (:Distance_Type), (:Direction_Type) or (:Payment_Category).

To find all the unique labels of nodes in your database, run the following:

```
match (n) return distinct labels(n)
```